# Chrome extension saving data (other options than local storage)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have to build a chrome extension that saves string of user data. What are the options that I can consider other than local storage?  
If I download the extension on another laptop then how can I ensure that data can be seen there. Is there a way to link google account to the chrome extension so that data can be stored and whenever you install the extension in some other device your data is there.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at storage.sync [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#using-sync).

This will automatically store the data in the users Google Account (if the user turned on synchronization in Chrome).

Comment: Thanks. This would require the user to login to the chrome browser, right? 

I don't plan to add any login functionality in the extension

Comment: The only special API extensions have is `chrome.storage` so if it doesn't suit, you will have to use the third-party services like dropbox and so on. There are lots of existing answers/articles for that.